# Fetching unmatched and matched rows from Mysql with many tables

Tags: mysql

I have this query generated on CodeIgneter but i dont get the results expected. Thanks for your help. the issue is if no subcategory added then the query not get all products added.

```
SELECT *, `products`.`created` AS `prod_created`, `products_details_translation`.`name` AS `prod_name`, `category_translation`.`name` AS `cat_name`, `subcategory_translation`.`name` AS `subcat_name` 
FROM `products` 
JOIN `products_details` ON `products`.`id`=`products_details`.`product_id`  
JOIN `products_details_translation` ON `products_details`.`product_details_id`=`products_details_translation`.`product_details_id`  
JOIN `products_images` ON `products`.`id`=`products_images`.`product_id`  
JOIN `products_category` ON `products`.`id`=`products_category`.`product_id`   
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`categoryID`=`products_category`.`prod_category_id`  
JOIN `category_translation` ON `category_translation`.`categoryID`=`category`.`categoryID`   
JOIN `subcategory` ON `subcategory`.`SubCategoryID`=`products_category`.`prod_subcat_id`  
JOIN `subcategory_translation` ON `subcategory_translation`.`SubCategoryID`=`subcategory`.`SubCategoryID`  
WHERE `products_details_translation`.`abbr` = 'en' AND `category_translation`.`abbr` = 'en' AND `subcategory_translation`.`abbr` = 'en'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used [simple join operators](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) you have restricted the recordset to only rows that match in all tables.
However just changing to *OUTER* joins will not be enough because you have also filtered on `subcategory_translation.abbr` which is the very last table in your join list.

1. Change your JOIN syntax to *LEFT JOIN*
2. Relax your filter criteria to allow null references

However because your translation filtering is to select a specific language, turning a `1 : many` recordset into a `1 : 1 or 0` we should move those filters to the join criteria, this will remove your where clause altogether.

```
SELECT *, `products`.`created` AS `prod_created`, `products_details_translation`.`name` AS `prod_name`, `category_translation`.`name` AS `cat_name`, `subcategory_translation`.`name` AS `subcat_name`
FROM `products` 
JOIN `products_details` ON `products`.`id`=`products_details`.`product_id`  
JOIN `products_images` ON `products`.`id`=`products_images`.`product_id`  
JOIN `products_category` ON `products`.`id`=`products_category`.`product_id`   
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`categoryID`=`products_category`.`prod_category_id`  
LEFT JOIN `subcategory` ON `subcategory`.`SubCategoryID`=`products_category`.`prod_subcat_id`  
LEFT JOIN `category_translation` ON `category_translation`.`categoryID`=`category`.`categoryID` AND `category_translation`.`abbr` = 'en'
LEFT JOIN `products_details_translation` ON `products_details`.`product_details_id`=`products_details_translation`.`product_details_id` AND `products_details_translation`.`abbr` = 'en'
LEFT JOIN `subcategory_translation` ON `subcategory_translation`.`SubCategoryID`=`subcategory`.`SubCategoryID` AND `subcategory_translation`.`abbr` = 'en'
```

Comment: Dear Chris, Thanks very much. i got the results now using row query but failed to get in codeigneter as i am getting error for "en" is not a column on ON clause like :$this->_categoryTranslationTable.'.categoryID='.$this->_categoryTable.'.categoryID AND '.$this->_categoryTranslationTable.'.abbr = `en`', "LEFT");

Comment: That sounds like a text encoding issue, make sure `'en'` is passed through as a string, or better yet use a parameter